# how to test a code which calls stored procedure

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

Im writing a .netCore application and try to test each part of the code im writing,but despite my personal desire i have to stored procedure ,i usually create an interface and implemet it and then call the interface in my controller,here is the implementation of my interface:

```
 public IEnumerable<OverviewData> overview(string regionalManager, string dtFrom, string dtTo)
    {
        regionalManager = "%";
        dtFrom = "2020/07/06";
        dtTo = "2020/07/07";
        string service_under = "%";
        string supervisor = "%";
        DateTime frm = Convert.ToDateTime(dtFrom);
        DateTime t = Convert.ToDateTime(dtTo);
        NpgsqlParameter p0 = new NpgsqlParameter("@dtfrom",System.Data.DbType.DateTime);
        NpgsqlParameter p1 = new NpgsqlParameter("@dtto", System.Data.DbType.DateTime);
        NpgsqlParameter p2 = new NpgsqlParameter("@regionalmanager", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
        NpgsqlParameter p3 = new NpgsqlParameter("@serviceunder", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
        NpgsqlParameter p4 = new NpgsqlParameter("@supervisor", NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
    
        var x = _db.dataInGlance.FromSqlRaw(@"SELECT * from wpv.avail_pro_api(@p0,@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4)
                            res (o_availability double precision, o_production double precision,o_numberofturbines integer, o_errors_disabled integer,o_failed_battery integer,o_power integer,o_crew_present text)", frm,t,regionalManager,service_under,supervisor
                          ).ToList();
        return x;
    }
```

I want to know how can i test it and in cases like mine which you have no choice but using the SP whats the best practice?what i have done is ok?

Comment: What does the use of stored procedure have to do with testability?

Comment: @Liam so in your opinion better not to use SP right?

Comment: @Crowcoder so having sp in the code means the code means you cant test your code

Comment: From a unit testing perspective, it literally doesn't matter. It's just a string as far as the unit test is concerned. The only thing you'd be testing here is that a hard coded string matched another hard coded string, which obviously would match, because they're hard coded. Which is why testing this would be pointless.

Comment: Are you talking about the business logic in the stored procedure? There are ways of testing database code, but agreed, it is generally difficult or not very useful to test stored procedures because they typically have no separation of concern.